# SQL Server - SSIS Reverting back to last step

Tags: ssis

Created a job which has got 15 steps - require to build our the datawarehouse.

But sometimes it skips few steps (for e.g missing the staging and start processing Dimension).

How can we build this - where at next steps it checks whether it has processed all staging or dimension or fact tables - If not then revert or reexcute the previous step again.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach to this is to provide the steps a mechanism they can use to determine if they have already done their work. At the last job, we had a business processing date table that was populated by an external process. Each unit of work was a Sequence Container that was an Execute SQL Task to a Data Flow to another Execute SQL Task.

[image: Control flow snippet]

In this example, the Test step determines what the last modified date was for X and writes that to a local variable @LastModDate.

The linkage between the Execute SQL and the Data Flow requires that the previous task succeeds *and* that the @LastModDate be greater than or equal to the BusinessDate which is determined at the start of the package.

And that's the pattern in a nutshell. Let a task inspect the system to determine whether there is work to be done. If so, let it process it and when it's complete, let it signal that the work is done.

The actual mechanics of how you implement the signaling and determination is a really variable entity. I've demonstrated one approach but plenty of others exist.